# Convert Map<string><string> in QuickSight

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, amazon-quicksight

I have a column of type Map string->string in Athena and this is not recognized in AWS QuickSight. I am trying to convert this field to varchar in QuickSight using SQL

```
SELECT cast(body as varchar) FROM db.events;
```

But it fails

```
Cannot cast map(varchar,varchar) to varchar
```

How can I convert this field correctly so QuickSight can query against it?

Comment: is "body" the column of type Map<String,String>?

Comment: @Dhaval yes it is

Comment: I am afraid there is no easy way to convert map to string. Map can have multiple entries.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is is no easy way to do that, but maybe there are some workarounds.

If each map has two keys with known names you can create two new columns:

```
SELECT 
    ELEMENT_AT(map_col,'key1') AS key1_col
    ,ELEMENT_AT(map_col,'key2') AS key2_col
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        MAP(
            ARRAY['key1','key2'], 
            ARRAY['val1','val2']
            ) AS map_col
    )
```

Which will output:

| key1_col | key2_col |
| --- | --- |
| val1 | val2 |

If your map column has just one key you can adapt the snippet above and use it or use this one:

```
SELECT 
    ARRAY_JOIN(MAP_KEYS(map_col), ', ') AS keys
    ,ARRAY_JOIN(MAP_VALUES(map_col), ', ') AS vals
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        MAP(
            ARRAY['key1'], 
            ARRAY['val1']
            ) AS map_col
    )
```

which will result in:

| keys | vals |
| --- | --- |
| key1 | val1 |

As said above, there is no correct way, if you have many keys you can try to use the second snippet to create strings to store keys and values, and later use calculated fields (maybe using split) to access them.

Hope it helps (: